# Cucumber steps fail for nested controller

Tags: cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3.2, minitest

I'm trying to implement a feature in my Rails 3 site using BDD:

```
Feature: Patents Administration

  Scenario: Patents index
    Given I am on the admin patents page
    Then I should see "Patents"
    And the title should be "Wavetronix - Patents"
```

And here are the corresponding steps:

```
Given /^I am on the (.*?) page$/ do |text|
  visit eval("#{text.downcase.gsub(/\s/, '_')}_path(locale: 'en')")
end

Then /^I should see "(.*?)"$/ do |text|
  page.must_have_selector('h1', text: text)
end

Then /^the title should be "(.*?)"$/ do |text|
  page.must_have_selector('title', text: text)
end
```

The first step fails as expected: I need to implement Admin::PatentsController:

```
module Admin
  class PatentsController < BaseController
    before_filter :find_patent

    def index

    end

  private

    def find_patent
      @patent = Patent.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]
    end
  end
end
```

Because it inherits from Admin::BaseController—which has its own index action and view:

```
module Admin
  class BaseController < ApplicationController

    filter_access_to :index

    def index
    end

  end
end
```

Admin::PatentsController inherits that action and view as well. When I override the BaseController implementation by explicitly defining an index action and view for the PatentsController, I can *see* the change in the browser—that it picks up the new index action and view—but the Cucumber step fails because it appears to still be looking at the BaseController index action and view.

I [created a gist](https://gist.github.com/3795013) with more code for reference.

Is this a bug? Is there a better way to test this?

Answer (score 0):

Bonehead: I am not accounting for existing authentication mechanism, which is redirecting because the test request isn't authenticated.